# On the definition of a Type

Tags: logic, type-theory

I am working through Spivak's text on category theory and he gives the definition of a type as :"A type is an abstract concept, a distinction the author has made". This seems very informal and after failing to find a precise definition on nlab I was wondering is a type truly just an abstract concept or does there exists a more formal definition?

Comment: "Type" can be defined to the same degree of formality as "set". So you might ask yourself first, what is a set?

Comment: A class which is an element of another class if memory serves.

Comment: Since I think you have just started studying types, you can think of a type as a proposition (this is the "proposition as types" paradigm, it's not the best one though) and terms of a type as evidences of the truth of the proposition or as proofs of the proposition (the latter one is a little problematic, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "type" is used for many different notions in mathematics and computer science. In your quotation from [*Category Theory for Scientists*](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/CT4S.pdf), Spivak is trying to give an intuitive explanation of the notion of type in the "OLog" ontology language.

Comment: Thank you, that has cleared it up quite a lot, so should I regard the aforementioned definition in Spivak's text as  the same as the definition in a study of type theory?

Comment: I very much doubt it, because the text you quote from Spivak falls far short of a definition. But who can say without knowing which "study of type theory" you have in mind?